# Preventing cutoffs with TranslateX

Tags: winrt-xaml

I have a ListView that needs a button placed to the immediate right of every item on the list. This means I need a button to be rendered *outside* of the thing it is part of, and the best method for this that I know of is TranlateX:

```
<Button>
    <Button.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform TranslateX="50"/>
    <Button.RenderTransform>
    <!-- ...other button stuff... -->
<Button>
```

This is getting my button outside of the box it's coming from, but it's also cutting off the right half of my button (well, the right-side 80% of it but you get the idea). How can I prevent this cutoff?

I'd like to avoid replacing the ListView if I can because it is really deeply ingrained into this app and I don't want to do a complete overhaul if it can be avoided.

PS: No, really, it has to be *outside* of the ListView. The ListView has an ItemContainerStyle that this button cannot be inside of. I can resize the ListView all day but that won't get the button on the outside.

Comment: can you post the xaml code?

Answer (score 1):

The `ListView` content is hosted inside of a `ScrollViewer` which will clip off anything that doesn't fit. I see two options for you.

1. Make the `ListView` wide enough for both the items and the buttons. Then just maybe you could force your items to be specific width (using `ItemContainerStyle/Style/Setter/Property/Width`) and use your transform to push it out. It's possible though that it will still clip your translated item. You would then have to retemplate each item based on [ListViewItem styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299136.aspx) to make the item chrome and container use less than the full space of the whole item and put the button in there.
2. You could put your button in a `Popup` or `Flyout`. I think realistically though - your button would only have to show up when you hover an item, as a `Popup` for each item would likely not scroll when you scroll the `ListView`. This of course could pose some problems for non-mouse use.

Answer (score 0):

So I actually solved this problem a few days after asking, but I don't think the solution is especially helpful to share. Basically I went into the (massive) code that controlled that border on the ListView and changed it to have a big margin, pushing it back inside of the ListView. TranslateX isn't even necessary anymore now that the ListView extends beyond the border.

So this problem isn't one that can be 'fixed' per se, only worked around in somehow.